# Bind ctrl+j/i/l/k to arrow keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I'm really wanting to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>I</kbd> / <kbd>L</kbd> / <kbd>K</kbd> to the arrow keys to make text editing quicker, but having trouble accomplishing this.

If anyone knows of an easy way to do this, I'd really appreciate it. I'm having trouble figuring out xbindkeys.